# Books on multivariable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, soft-question

I'm looking for a book that covers the following subjects: multivariable functions, extremes of multivariable functions, integration, implicit function theorems, functions defined by integrals, vector valued functions, Green's theorem, Stokes theorem, divergence theorem, second order ODEs.

I need to learn this for work reasons so in looking for a book that's **primarily easy to follow and very intuitive as to why stuff works. Extreme formality is not a necessity at the moment.**

Also, could all this be learned in about a week of uninterrupted study?

E: Considering the 1-2 week deadline a secondary stretch goal and prioritizing reading ease, what would be the best option?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why the rush? It seems like a lot to learn in a week and internalise everything ...

Comment: I have that much time available right now (maybe up to two weeks), but I have know most of this in order to get a particular job afterwards.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: To be honest, even two weeks will be a stretch. If you are diligent and have good mathematical intuition, you can probably cover the material in that time. But even then, it is unlikely that you will have spent enough time with each subject to have a solid understanding that you can readily draw from.

Comment: In terms of just memorizing the methods taught in a typical multivariable calculus class, I'd say it is very easy to do in a week. But this isn't how you learn something, and it will be easily lost after the week.

Comment: I wrote a short set of notes (15 pages) called "[Quick Calculus](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By3lNuPto1AidFMxLUFzUzRnSkk/view?usp=sharing)" that attempts to derive the main results of calculus very quickly, using intuition rather than rigor.  You could try taking a look.

Comment: Intuition and rigour shouldn't exclude eachother - try smooth infinitesimal analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to just cram that stuff into your head, you can find it all in Do Carmo's Differential Geometry in the chapter appendixes where it is offered as review. To be honest, you could find summaries of that stuff on wikipedia. Really all you're asking for is to know a few formulas - how to optimize multivariable functions, do vector calculus and then the theorems you listed above. You won't get much out of it at all that way, but I guess that's why I'm telling you it's really just for cramming sake.

If you want to learn something, even if it takes longer, I might suggest the books by Zorich, which I always liked. If you use these books, it will take you a while, but you will come to understand deeply what is going on when you are applying these ideas you're discussing. There is some emphasis on the implicit and inverse function theorems, which are really important theorems that arise in analysis, at the end. I don't know what kind of work you're looking for, but in my work, I use these theorems much more than Green or Stokes.

Comment: I don't really want to just memorize stuff, I want to learn, I have a tight schedule but I'll try my best to learn as much as I can within that time, even if I can make to 40-50% that should be enough for the meantime. The job I've been offered is kind of hard to explain, I'd develop some physics applications for the physics dept. of a (new-ish) university. They require, besides the coding part (which I've got), a basic understand of the maths they use, what I've listed are their requirement (seem like a standard multivariable calc course).

Comment: While I self-studied most I know about Linear Algebra, Singlevariable calculus, elementary set theory and abstract algebra, I've never studied multivariable calc.